# Extracting all but a certain phrase using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a string that I want to extract all but a certain pattern into another variable.

```
first_string = "Q13 Hello, World!"
```

I'd like to get the `Hello, World!` out of the string and into another variable so that: `second_string = "Hello, World!"`.

I attempted to create a regex that extracts all but the "Q13" and it works on Rubular but not in the console.

```
> first_string = "Q13 Hello, World!"
> second_string = first_string.scan(/[^(Q[0-9]{1,})]/)
=>  [" ", "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d", "!"] 
> second_string.join()
=> " Hello World!"
```

This is fine but I can't lose the leading space using the regex. That wouldn't be a problem except I have some application specific caveats...

Not all strings will have "Q13"... the "Q" will be there but the number will change. I don't know if "Q13" will come at the beginning or end of the text.  I can't be certain what text will be in the string.

I can't rely on the leading space being there.  It might also be a trailing space.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Do you want to include leading/trailing spaces? Could the mystery text include digits and in particular, could it start with digits? Does the pattern you want to remove always consist of 'Q' followed by one more more digits, and terminated by a non-digit character?

Comment: What might the excluded text look like besides "Q13 "?

Comment: What about `newstr = string.scan(/(?:(.*?)\s(?=Q\d+)|Q\d+\s(?=(.*?)$))/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to omit the Q[number] and any surrounding whitespace:

```
second_string = first_string.gsub(/\s?Q\d+\s?/, "")
```

If you want to omit the Q[number] but not the surrounding whitespace:

```
second_string = first_string.gsub(/Q\d+/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
second_string = first_string.scan(/\A(?:Q[0-9]+)?(?: )?(.*?)(?: )?(?:Q[0-9]+)?\z/).flatten.first
```

#### Live test in Ruby console

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > first_string = "Q12 Hello World! Q87"
 => "Q12 Hello World! Q87"
2.0.0p247 :002 > second_string = first_string.scan(/\A(?:Q[0-9]+)?(?: )?(.*?)(?: )?(?:Q[0-9]+)?\z/).flatten.first
 => "Hello World!"
```